# export CSV to MySQL

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

I want to do something really simple. 
I just want to export excel data to a CSV in order to put it in a Mysql DB.

It is a huge excel so I can't manage exceptions easily.

My problem is that when I save my xslx into csv, it put me the `"` to separate columns only if there is a comma in the column or if there is already a `"` so I have something like that in my CSV :

```
col1 | col2 | col3 => col1,col2,col3
col1 | co,l2| col3 => col1,"co,l2",col3 
col1 |"col"2| col3 => col1,"""col""2",col3 
col1 |      | col3 => col1,,col3
```

So I tried a lot of tings to convert it for SQL but i don't find a good way.

I work in Excel 2007 and SQL want to CSV to have this config:

```
Columns separated with: ,
Columns enclosed with: "
Columns escaped with: \
Lines terminated with: auto
```

Comment: MySQL  `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFLILE` has a `COLUMNS SEPARATED BY` argument you can use without even converting.

Comment: MySQL should not be looking at commas inside quotes if you use the correct params

Comment: Thats perfectly normal/sane CSV rules. If there is no reason to added quotes, then it doesn't. (Quotes must be added if the data contains either quotes or commas - the separator. See the relevant wikipedia article.)

Comment: thank you. It helped me. I succeed thanks to Kevin solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to [load your data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) using

```
LOAD DATA FROM INFILE 'filename.csv'
INTO TABLE tablename
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

The `OPTIONALLY` is actually ignored when loading a file, or to phrase it a better way, even if you don't specify `OPTIONALLY`, the enclosing will still be treated as optional. Which means that a column value *may* be enclosed in quotation marks, but *need not* be. Note that afaik. Excel does not use `\` to escape values.

If you need some other format for purposes other than importing into MySQL, then you may re-export the data from MySQL afterwards, with the settings you prefer. When [writing a file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html), omitting the `OPTIONALLY` will turn quotes on for every value.